# HTML5 tag dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, nav, dropdown

I am working on a HTML5 dorpdown menu for fun. 
I was reading on W3Schools about a dropdown menu but all of them are using CSS classes and id's.

the HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Super cool drop down menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Super cool drop down menu!</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#Link1">Link 1</a>
                    <li><a href="#Link2">Link 2</a>
                    <li><a href="#Link3">Link 3</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


    <h3>Super cool dropdown menu</h3>
    <p>Ga met je muis op Super cool dorp down menu! staan om de linkjes te tonen.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the style.css has the following code:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li ul li {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    display: block;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

nav ul li ul li a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I think I got it almost working but it doesn't show the second ul li elements. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you are setting the nested list items to "display: none".

```
nav ul li ul li {
    display: none;
    ...
}
```

If you want them to appear when the parent li element is hovered use something like the following css:

```
nav ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

I made a jsfiddle to play around with it:

https://jsfiddle.net/1zq1s9ea/

There may have been a couple other minor changes that I made such as closing all of the the 'li' tags, but the one you needed was the one I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: I got one more question. My code is showing the last list item element. It isn't showing the list properly. Do you know what I am doing wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/1zq1s9ea/2/

Comment: You are absolutely positioning all of the list elements in that menu, so they are all appearing one on top of the menu. Instead, try absolutely positioning the ul, and positioning the li elements relative to their parent. 

https://jsfiddle.net/1zq1s9ea/3/

The way I investigated the issue was to use Chrome developer tools (hit f12 when the site is open in Chrome). You can inspect the elements on the page and see all of the elements positions (even invisible ones) and what css is applied to them.

Comment: Oh bro you don't want to know how long I spend on this script xD. Thanks a lot for it!